# Guess the version of math library in c

Tags: c, math, version

I am building a process in C with the library math, and is important for me to write the version I am using.
There are some function or macro in math.h that returns his version?

Comment: I'm not sure that individual libraries have versions, as such. But, if you want to know to what C Standard your code is being (was) compiled to, you can use the `__STDC_VERSION__` macro. [How can I know the version of c?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36662063/10871073)

Comment: _There are some function or macro in math.h that returns his version?_ I don't think so, but `find /usr/lib -name "libm.so.*"` must return something useful, in my case `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6`: version 6. You can pass this information from a Makefile using `gcc ... -DMATH_VERSION=6`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add some background information about your software, the system(s) where you build and run it, and why you need to know the library version. You could check the version of the libraries during the build process. If your software is dynamically linked, which is the standard on commonly used platforms, the exact version of the shared library on the target system might differ from the libraries on the build system. In this case you might need additional (system specific) checks.

Comment: I found the functions gnu_get_libc_version and gnu_get_libc_release. Although these functions are valid just for GNU, I think they return the version of all c libraries. And one of them is libm.so (the math library). And... yes, Adrian: probably an individual library has not an isolated version.